# How to config two primary keys with data annotation in entity framework core?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to config two primary keys for my model using data annotation in entity framework core

```
public class OTP
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   
   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

I tried some solution in the internet but it did not work.

can somebody help me, thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

The syntax you are using is for EF 6.0 not EF Core. If you are using EF Core 7.0 you can use the `primary key` annotation which goes before the class declaration , i.e. Something like:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(Id), nameof(User))] 
public class OTP 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

In older versions you need to use the fluent API for composite keys.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OTP>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id , c.User });
}
```

For further reading [see the online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations#configuring-a-primary-key).

As an aside, I have limited experience with data annotations as I've always used the fluent API, but I would typically link the `User` via the primitive type key, i.e. Assuming `User` has a primary key of `UserId`:

```
public class OTP 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual User User { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Then map the foreign key:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<OTP>().HasKey(c => new { c.Id , c.User });
    modelBuilder.Entity<OTP>()
        .HasOne(e => e.User)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.Userid);
}
```